# sql split field by comma delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following.

```
Products_Joined.METATAG_Keywords AS Keyword,
```

This returns this for "keyword"

```
shoe,sneaker,boot,slipper
```

I am tying to split this into separate fields as so.

```
keyword1    shoe
keyword2    sneaker
keyword3    boot
keyword4    slipper
```

Something like a Javascript split function on comma delimiter.

Unfortunately this is how this field is stored in the database.

EDIT: Although I do not think it matters much I have provided the full sql query, perhaps someone can tell which version of SQL this is.

```
SELECT
'home-and-garden-products > home decorations > rugs' AS Category,
SUBSTRING(Products_Joined.ProductName, 6,LEN(Products_Joined.ProductName)) AS [stripHTML-Title],
'Config_FullStoreURL' + 'ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=' + Products_Joined.IsChildOfProductCode AS Link,
Products_Joined.ProductCode AS SKU,
CAST(IsNull(Products_Joined.SalePrice,Products_Joined.ProductPrice) AS VARCHAR(30)) AS Price,
Products_Joined.ProductManufacturer AS Brand,
Products_Joined.UPC_code AS UPC,
'Config_FullStoreURLConfig_ProductPhotosFolder/' + IsNull(Products_Joined.IsChildOfProductCode,Products_Joined.ProductCode) + '-2T.jpg' AS Image,
Products_Joined.ProductDescription AS [stripHTML-DESCRIPTION],
Products_Joined.ProductManufacturer AS Manufacturer,
Products_Joined.vendor_partno AS [Mfr part number],
'0' AS [Shipping Cost],
Products_Joined.Google_Color AS Color,
Products_Joined.Google_Material AS Material,
Products_Joined.ProductWeight AS [Shipping Weight], 
Products_Joined.Google_Size AS Size,
Products_Joined.METATAG_Keywords AS Keyword,
Products_Joined.ProductWeight AS Weight
FROM Products_Joined WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (Products_Joined.ProductPrice > 0) 
AND (Products_Joined.IsChildOfProductCode IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY Products_Joined.ProductCode
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find that [this page](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) contains the solution you're looking for.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In what way is it not working? Error messages or description of incorrect results would be very helpful, if you don't mind.

Comment: I edited the question and added the complete query. Not sure where to add that code that you linked to.

Comment: +1 for the link. I would also added `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` in the function: `insert into @temptable(Items) values(LTRIM(RTRIM(@slice)))`.

Comment: Can someone explain where to insert the SQL function shown in the link above?

Comment: @user357034 You need to copy the code for `CREATE FUNCTION ...` and run it in Management Studio, now you will have a new table-valued function which you can use e.g. this way: `SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@String,',') `

Answer (score 1):

Check out this SPLIT Function which I hope would provide the solution you are looking for - http://vadivel.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-split-delimited-string-values-in.html