# mysql group by comma separated values

Tags: mysql, select, tags

I have a mysql table comments in that table a field is tags and all tags are comma separated like

***Comments Table***

```
Name   Reply   Tags
a      b       new,old,facebook,fb
b      d       water,faebook,wall
b      r       wall,php,fb
c      q       name,facebook,email
a      y       weather,cold,old
a      w       twitter,next,pet,fb
```

I need to get most used tag in this table with mysql query..

Comment: Consider refactoring your database design and store the tags for Name/Reply combinations in a separate table, with one row for each tag.

Comment: You should _really_ try to normalize your table, MySQL is really not very good at splitting strings. The query is doable, but not very efficient.

Comment: if you can not normalize the database then it can only be done in php script level.

Comment: Is the set of tags fixed? In other words, do you have a list of possible tags in another table?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best approach is to use a separate table for Tags and for the relation between Tags and your table (i.e.: CommentTags), it'll allow you to quickly find those comments that use any speciffic tag, do statistics, etc. With your current approach, you end up using a string splitting for each row, each time.

Now, if you are stuck with your current approach, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774865/sql-split-field-by-comma-delimiter) is a question about string splitting that you may find useful. But I foresee a great deal of performance complains by users...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but my database is not normalized so can i get this....

@Joachim Isaksson how can i do this in PHP..